# Create a collection of functions tupled with a collection of parameters, and execute the collection in order in Scala

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I am trying to create a collection of `Unit` functions that have any arity and type, and will execute them in order.

This is the working implementation that I have:

```
/** A Subroutine simply represents a unit function that takes any number of parameters. */
type Subroutine = (Any) => Unit

/** A Routine represents a collection of functions which may consume a collection of parameters and will always
  * complete an action.
  */
type Routine = List[(Subroutine, Seq[_])]

/** This function will consume a list of functions executing them in order.
  *
  * @param routine is the list of functions and their parameters to be consumed.
  */
def executeRoutine(routine: Routine): Unit = {
  routine.headOption match {
    case Some((f, x)) =>
      f(x)
      executeRoutine(routine.tail)
    case None => ()
  }
}
```

and when I declare a function or "subroutine", I have to declare it like this in order to extract the parameters:

```
def myFunction: Subroutine = {
  case (firstParam: Int) :: (secondParam: String) :: _ => ...
  case _ => throw new InvalidParameterException()
}

def myFunction2: Subroutine = {
  case (firstParam: Int) :: _ => ...
  case _ => throw new InvalidParameterException()
}

val routine: Routine = List(
  (myFunction, Seq(firstParam, secondParam)),
  (myFunction2, Seq(firstParam))
)
```

I realize that this is not close to idiomatic Scala code, and I've been working on implementing a different approach which will partially apply functions one parameter at a time, and then execute the function after the parameters are fully applied. I do not yet have a working version of this approach, but this is as far as I have gotten:

```
/** A Subroutine simply represents a unit function that takes any number of parameters. */
sealed abstract class Subroutine extends (Any => Unit)

case class Curried(partiallyApplied: Function[_, Function[_, _]], unapplied: Function[_, _]) extends Subroutine

case class Uncurried(function: Function[_, Unit]) extends Subroutine

/** A Routine represents a collection of functions which may consume a collection of parameters and will always
  * complete an action.
  * Using HList for the parameters, from Shapeless
  */
type Routine = List[(Subroutine, HList)]

/** This function will consume a list of functions executing them in order.
  *
  * @param routine is the list of functions and their parameters to be consumed.
  */
def executeRoutine(routine: Routine): Unit = {
  routine.headOption match {
    case Some((f, x)) =>
      executeSubroutine(f, x)
      executeRoutine(routine.tail)
    case None => ()
  }
}

private def executeSubroutine(subroutine: Subroutine, params: HList): Any = {
  subroutine match {
    case Curried(partiallyApplied, unapplied) =>
      partiallyApplied(params.head)(executeSubroutine(unapplied, params.tail))
    case Uncurried(function) => function(params.head)
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) "[The norm is to summarize the goal of the code in the title.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: So to clarify, you have a working implementation that you would like reviewed, and another non-working implementation for reference?

Answer (score -1):

Unless I misunderstand your question, I think this is what you want:

```
type Subroutine[Param] = Param => Any

type Routine = Seq[(Subroutine[_], Seq[Any])]

def execRoutine(routine: Routine): Unit = routine foreach { case (sub, params) => execSubroutine(sub, params) }

def execSubroutine[SubParam] (subroutine: Subroutine[SubParam], params: Seq[Any]): Unit = {
    require(params.nonEmpty)

    subroutine(params.head.asInstanceOf[SubParam]) match {
        case sub: Subroutine[_] => execSubroutine(sub, params.tail)
        case () => require(params.tail.isEmpty) // Require correct number of params.
        case _ => throw new IllegalStateException()
    }
}

val add2 = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => println(a + b)
val add3 = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) => println(a + b + c)

execRoutine(List(
    (add2, List(3, 4)),
    (add3, List(3, 4, 5))
))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJLawIxED6vv2KOCV0UansRWvDgQWhpUXqSRWazY01Zs2uSrYr4222y7svSeggkM99rhhiBKZ7PWfxFwsIrSgW0t6QSA@M8h2OvF9hDTjAvYp0VVipavKPGTQRPUF7g6RnG6lDjZheQ685pu2Ad2jIKy5oDRzxy@IRWzotERWEVcFRr8BF8KGmdVNWBVaYJxRqOINAQMFPEIeQ@heE@h1drHa/bp45jJ5W7VvN4eBPhL0StNWrHaBIee0GgaVtITeyC6qtMTTa5PXBnHLTadXtNmPTRTJWxqAS9rVojDhu0fkxHDMpJHf0q0zK6PW7fokx5Q2fldn7l85C@NJeMMBjA7NIHkWntP4MqNjFpyFa1aKO39HJ2rbMdKNrBNE3pE9O5RUuTvaDcykwxb3/qBX7v35gCJsm9WxTDEUyVLQOxuL3nWiqbKoZwBzFvKMMbFCb@obsj/Na7n@tFGstcIuZzhFA@hyE8cB5W1WGnGsIjdyHcOZ3PPw)

This program prints 7 and 12. Unfortunately, if the parameters are of the wrong type, a runtime exception occurs instead of a compile time one. Attempting to apply the less or more than the required parameters also results in a runtime exception.

Comment: So does the OP's cod enot work, or yours?

Comment: @Dannnno The OP's code does not work, as they stated, but my code does compile and run correctly. Does that address your question?